# Some symbols are not rendered in Linux/Plasma5

Tags: linux, fonts, unicode, plasma

I have Opensuse Tumbleweed with all the latest updates installed on my laptop and my PC, on my laptop with same font `CURLY BRACKET SECTION` symbols are rendered, but on my PC they are not, I see only weird block symbol you usually see when font does not have the symbol in question.

I did verify that I have that same font and that same version of the font on both systems and $LANG is also the same (en_GB.utf8)

I also looked through all the fonts installed on my system via kcharselect and all of them display some kind of placeholder instead of these symbols.

Comment: From my experience this issue has nothing to do with the locale of the system.
Switched locales problem persists.

Comment: @Cosmonauth yes, I've just posted an answer. The problem was missing font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research and getting advice from online communities, I've found out that my premise was wrong. The symbols are not available in the font I thought they were coming from.

The system which was displaying the symbols correctly was just falling back to a font which was installed there and wasn't installed on my PC.

This is the command which helped to identify which:

```
FC_DEBUG=4 pango-view -q -t '⎱' 2>&1 |grep -o 'family: "[^"]\+' | cut -c 10- | tail -n 1
```

The font turned out to be `FreeMono`.

The symbol is the one quoted after `-t` parameter.

Also answers from this question helped: https://superuser.com/questions/876572/how-do-i-find-out-which-font-contains-a-certain-special-character